# BIOS Update from bootable usb

Tags: bios

I want to do an BIOS Update for an Lenovo ThinkCentre.
I try using the .iso file from the official site [BIOS Update (ISO Image Version)](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/eg/de/products/desktops-and-all-in-ones/thinkcentre-m-series-desktops/thinkcentre-m910x/10my/10mya00jmd/pc0qepea/downloads/ds120436?Products=DESKTOPS-AND-ALL-IN-ONES%2FTHINKCENTRE-M-SERIES-DESKTOPS%2FTHINKCENTRE-M910X%2F10MY%2F10MYA00JMD%2FPC0QEPEA)
And following this guide: [How to update Lenovo BIOS from Linux](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/update-lenovo-bios-from-linux-usb-stick-pen/)

But I already fail at the `Extract the image from iso file` step using `geteltorito`.
Has anyone an advice how to accomplish this?

I want to do the BIOS update cause the usb ports seem to be buggy at some points and reset them.

Comment: Please copy and paste the exact `geleltorito ..........` command you entered and the exact error you got into your question.

Comment: I made a Windows PE iso file, and it can be used to create a USB boot drive and get a system, that can be used to update the BIOS. I have updated BIOS from the current BIOS in a Dell computer, but I have not used the method you are trying. The tutorial text looks good, but it also states that "the difficulty level is advanced", so maybe you must try a few times until you succeed.

Comment: Did you use the command `sudo apt install genisoimage` before using the `geteltorito......` command? It may be better if you enter `history` in the terminal and copy and paste the part from the beginning of the instructions you followed.

Comment: @sudodus Thanks for the hint! Sounds much easier to create a bootable windows stick and use the bios.exe file to update it. I'll try that.

Comment: Good luck @temp :-)

Comment: Newer Lenovo are in fwupdate and can be directly updated from Linux. https://fwupd.org/lvfs/devicelist Check for your model ThinkCentre, many shown in list.